# Flutter Camera overlay with square

Tags: android, ios, flutter, camera, qr-code

I want to have one square overlay on camera for QR code, which captures QR code as it is. I am attaching an image for reference.[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zipKj.jpg)